# Copying from reference column based on neighboring cell value

Tags: excel, reference, vba

I have been trying to create a macro or a formula in order to do the following, but since Ive becomes stumped- I'm going to reach out to you guys for help.

What I would like to achieve is the macro to be able to copy from the active cell downward based on reference to a neighbouring cell. This neighbouring cell, we can call it the reference cell.

This macro is supposed to copy from the active cell downward as long as the reference column is not empty and the macro is also to be smart enough to skip downward when a blank reference cell is encountered and go onto the next reference cell until the last filled cell.

Is it possible to do something like that?

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is neighbouring cell mean one cell to the right? Or left or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for you to work from, it assumes the Neighbor column is one over to the right:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngDiff As Long

Set rngStart = ActiveCell
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, rngStart.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row

lngDiff = lngLastRow - rngStart.Row + 1

Set rngStart = rngStart.Resize(lngDiff)
rngStart.Select
End Sub
```