# MERGE EXCEL ROWS BASED ON REFERENCE COLUMN VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to merge different rows in column B based on a referring value from column A and copy the result to column C.

**Input:**

```
CODE    NAME
110001  Baroda House
110001  Bengali Market
110002  Bhagat Singh Market
110002  Connaught Place
125051  Constitution House
125051  Election Commission
125051  Janpath
125051  Krishi Bhawan
125051  Lady Harding Medical College
```

Expected Output:

```
CODE    NAME                ;MERGED
110001  Baroda House        ;Baroda House,Bengali Market
110001  Bengali Market      ;Baroda House,Bengali Market
110002  Bhagat Singh Market ;Bhagat Singh Market,Connaught Place
110002  Connaught Place     ;Bhagat Singh Market,Connaught Place
125051  Constitution House  ;Constitution House,Election Commission,Janpath,Krishi Bhawan,Lady Harding Medical College
125051  Election Commission ;Constitution House,Election Commission,Janpath,Krishi Bhawan,Lady Harding Medical College
125051  Janpath             ;Constitution House,Election Commission,Janpath,Krishi Bhawan,Lady Harding Medical College
125051  Krishi Bhawan       ;Constitution House,Election Commission,Janpath,Krishi Bhawan,Lady Harding Medical College
```

I tried with the macro given here, but its not working:
[Copying from reference column based on neighboring cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237538/copying-from-reference-column-based-on-neighboring-cell-value)

Can anybody help me. The xlsx file has 114000 rows.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "its not working" is not a good problem discription. What is not working, what error message do you get, is the output <> desired output? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet3" Then 'if statement to exclude this sheet, add more if any need excluding
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row with data
        Repeated = 1
        For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop through rows
            Newvalue = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value 'get the code to compare
            For x = 2 To LastRow 'loop again for comparison
                If ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = Newvalue Then
                    Merged = Merged & "; " & ws.Cells(x, 2).Value 'if values match then get the merged value
                    Repeated = Repeated + 1 'Increment if match found
                    ID = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
                End If
            Next x
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Merged 'enter the value on column C
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = ID & " repeated " & Repeated - 1 & " times."
            Merged = "" 'Clear the variable for next loop
            Repeated = 1 'clear variable ready for next loop
        Next i
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested this and it will include as many matches as are found... as the second loop will check from the beginning to the end to see if any matches are found...

Comment: Ah I see now, I was mistaken.

Comment: @Xabier, super its working exactly as i expected. Can plz show me the count of Column A cell value repeated in column D along with the result.Ex:-110001 repeated 2 times,110002 repeated 2 times and 125051 repeated 5 times, so column D will show the count of value repeated in column A.

Comment: @Ram I've updated my answer to reflect your new comments.

Comment: @Xabier, i found the solution to show the count of the values repeated i column A, just pasted the result in column A and applied this formula in column B. and its working. Thanks:=LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))+1

Comment: @Xabier, Many thanks for updating the Macro, thanks a lot, you saved my time.

Comment: @Xabier, sorry for troubling you again, How can i apply this macro to all sheets in workbook?

Comment: @Ram Updated my answer to include your new comments, also included an if statement to let you have the option to exclude any specific sheets from the macro. :)

Comment: @Xabier, you are awesome man, thanks a lot. Its working. Just checked now.